# fancybox 2 & IE8 - no background overlay

Tags: fancybox-2

I'm using fancybox 2 and have an issue with background overlay [ with transparency ].
My overlay helper looks like:

```
overlay : {
        css : {
            'background' : 'rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.95)'
        }
    }
```

And as I've red rgba is not compatible with IE<-8

----- SOLUTION ----------

I've found this solution:

```
overlay : {
        css : {
    'background':'transparent',
            'filter':'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient
             (startColorstr=#F22a2a2a,endColorstr=#F22a2a2a)', 
            'zoom': '1',
            'background' : 'rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.95)'
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you need to set "transparency" ... if you can set "opacity" with the `helpers` option that is compatible with IE7+ ? just curious.

Comment: because opacity will be applied also to child elements but RGBA only to that DIV

Comment: the `overlay` DIV has not child elements

Comment: Upvoted for working solution.

Comment: @michalzahor thanks for posting this.  I too had this issue and i solved it using your solution but for the class .fancybox-skin i am having issues.  That is the class that holds the popup.  The background is #f9f9f9 but it appears transparent on IE 8.  DId you also have this issue?